# Cloudkit's fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler: not calling completion handler on certain devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud, cloudkit

```
    _container = [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"iCloud.com.komocode.TestApp"];
    _privateDatabase = [_container privateCloudDatabase];
   [_privateDatabase fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *subscriptions, NSError *error) {
      // Never called
      NSLog(@"Test");
   }];
```

This piece of code only works on my iPad, but on my iPhone 6, the completion handler never gets called. Both my iPad and iPhone 6 are logged into the same iCloud account. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rebooting the phone fixed it... I guess CloudKit is not ready for production?